# Vertically center <li> text with bullet image?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

So I am trying to figure out how I can vertically align some text that I have with a custom bullet image. Here is what I have:

```
<ul>
    <li>LINE OF TEXT</li>
    <li>LINE OF TEXT</li>
    <li>LINE OF TEXT</li>
</ul>
```

And for the CSS...

```css
#div .class
{
    color: #4c361c;
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style-image: url(../images/image.png);
}

#div .class li{ }
```

Does anyone have anyideas on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Play with the `line-height` of the `<li>`s.

Comment: What is the dimension of your bullet image?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mV3vk/12/).

Using a background image can get you the desired effect.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
  background: url('../imgpath/bullet-image.png') no-repeat left center;

  /* Adjust the padding for your custom bullet image */
  padding: 10px 0 10px 34px;
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue. Using `list-style: none;`, assign a background image to the li and use padding to have the text bumped out away from the bullet itself.

Answer (score 2):

**Now Define** you `li` `background bullets` and set to `background-position` according to **your design**

as like this

**Css**

```
ul{
margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
li {
background:url("http://www.un.org/en/oaj/unjs/efiling/added/images/bullet-list-icon.jpg") no-repeat 0 -2px;
  padding-left:20px;
  line-height:14px;
  font-size:14px;
  margin-top:12px;
}
```

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/CRvdjBhx)***

Comment: dead link I'm afraid :(